# How to keep the value if function is true?

Tags: c

I have `lagersaldot` where if the user chooses `1` it adds a number and if it chooses `2` it subtracts a number from it. But if it chooses 2, and the number is `<0` how can I keep the old value? let's say that lagersaldot is 10 and chooses to subtract 15 which is under 0 it should keep its value 10.

```
    void updateLagersaldo(struct varor reg[], int nrOfGoods){
        int i, varunummer, change;
        printf("Enter Varunummer: ");// identify the item and change lagersaldo
        scanf("%d", &varunummer);
        i= ifVarunummerExist(varunummer, reg, nrOfGoods);
        printf("\nVarunummer \t Namn \t\t\t Lagersaldo\n");
        printf(" %d \t\t %s \t\t\t %d\n",reg[i].varunummer,reg[i].namn,reg[i].lagersaldo);
        if(i >= 0){
            char choice;
            printf("\n (1) Sum lagersaldot \n (2) Subtract lagersaldot");
            scanf(" %c%*c", &choice);
            if(choice=='1'){
                printf("Sum lagersaldot with: ");
                scanf("%d", &change);
                reg[i].lagersaldo+=change;
            }

//HERE IF CHOICE IS 2 IF LAGERSALDO<0
            if(choice=='2'){
                printf("Subtract lagersaldot with: ");
                scanf("%d", &change);
                reg[i].lagersaldo-=change;
                if(reg[i].lagersaldo<0){
                    printf("Error! Can't be under 0 !!");
                    return;
                }
            }

        }else printf("Varunummer not exist!\n");
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the result of the subtraction before assigning the variable to it?

Comment: @Kevin do you mean if i checked if it keeps its value after? I did it doesn't

Comment: No, I mean `if (reg[i].lagersaldo-change < 0) { error } else { do subtraction }`

Comment: @Kevin I don't know why that didn't cross my mind. I fixed it now, thank you !

Comment: @Kevin Please make an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the check before doing the subtraction:

```
if (reg[i].lagersaldo - change < 0) {
    printf("Error! Can't be under 0 !!");
    return;
}
reg[i].lagersaldo -= change;
```